# How to employ React Thinking

Tags: reactjs, pseudocode

I have taken several react courses that walk through building applications. The courses teach syntax and concepts. But how you solve a problem using react is different!
I am a dinosaur web person who is used to html/javascript.

In terms of a real-world example, such an enterprise level component, how do you tackle it? Do you follow a process where you write pseudo code first? Do you start with writing your code all in one file, and then break them into their own components?

I was going to try to create a modal component (I am sure they exist in a million places already) but for the sake of understanding, but I immediately get hung up in my own confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use some simple components like modals, buttons etc., you can use one of the popular component libraries like [Material UI](https://mui.com).